# register users automatically

Tags: users

I add a new text field that called real name(for entering the real first and last name).
And a "selection filed" that user can select his field between A to D.

Now for registration we have 5 field.

1. Email
2. Username
3. Password
4. Real name
5. "Selection field"

And I have an Excel file that contains about 500 users data(all data are in there such as user name and password and ...)

Now I need a similar code to register them automatically in my drupal site.

How?

Note:In the "selection field" the choice are such as First-one First-two and so on.

Example:this is a similar column in my excel file

```
Username     password     realname     Email     SelectionFild
12321        12321        Mr.Bin       -         F1
```

Note:in this example - in the Email means the user haven't Email address.
And F1 in the selection field means First-one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [feeds](https://drupal.org/project/feeds) module which import data, uses, taxonomy term into Drupal website using CSV file.

In module page:

> Import or aggregate data as nodes, users, taxonomy terms or simple
>   database records.
>
> - One-off imports and periodic aggregation of content
> - Import or aggregate RSS/Atom feeds
> - Import or aggregate CSV files
> - Import or aggregate OPML files
> - Create nodes, users, taxonomy terms or simple database records from import
> - Extensible to import any other kind of content
> - Granular mapping of input elements to Drupal content elements
> - Exportable configurations Batched import for large files